# How does one evaluate $\int f_j 1_{A_j} \ d \mu$

Tags: integration

How does one evaluate the Lebesgue integral $$ \int f_j 1_{A_j} \ d \mu$$ for functions $f_j$ (measurable)?
I know the Lebesgue integral of the characteristic function is just $\mu(A_j)$, but what now?

EDIT: (Please explain $\text{why}$ as well).

Comment: There is no essential difference between evaluating $\int fd\mu$ (where $f$ is an integrable function and evaluating $\int f_j1_{A_j}d\mu$ where $f_j1_{A_j}$ is an integrable function.

Answer (score 0):

Now that you've defined the integral for a characteristic function, you can do it for simple functions, then for non-negative measurable functions, and finally for integrable functions. That's the usual path in an integration course.